# Getting cookie from jQuery post response

Tags: jquery, post, cookies

I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 to submit to a remote login form. Everything works as expected in terms of response, as I can see it in the browser console. In the response headers, I also see Set-Cookie: .... Problem is, the cookie is not set, neither I can't seem to access it.

Here's my code:

```
            $.post ( "https://server/admin/", 
                { j_username: "user", j_password: "pass", secure: "true" }, 
                function(data, status, xhr){
                    var ck = xhr.getResponseHeader('Set-Cookie');
                    console.log(ck);
                }
        );
```

Console log shows "null", despite Set-Cookie on the response headers.

Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does document.cookie give you?

Comment: document.cookie seems to output empty string

Comment: Still can't access Set-Cookie, but throw proper headers on the server I was able to get the cookie to bet on the browser, so I can access and use document.cookie now.